# Join Query in magento 2

Tags: database, magento2.2, join-table

**The below code entry is already in DB, Now I need to add one field to customer id and want to rerun this code via programmatically.**

```
$this->getSelect()->join(
                    ['detail' => $this->getReviewDetailTable()], 'main_table.review_id = detail.review_id', ['detail_id', 'title', 'detail', 'nickname', 'customer_id']
            );
```

I have created a custom module from for  Product Review. In above I have overrides the Magento review collection class, while overriding this part shows error as

> You cannot define a correlation name 'detail' more than once

**So Now In my override class I have added the one more field, But DB has the entry already. I also need to handle this while updating or overriding   in my class so pls provide me a solution**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below query

```
$this->getSelect()->join(
                    ['details' => $this->getReviewDetailTable()], 'main_table.review_id = details.review_id', ['detail_id', 'title', 'detail', 'nickname', 'customer_id']
            );
```

Comment: What is the difference between the above code and your answer. Please explain

Comment: I have change table alias 'detail' to 'detials'

Comment: My issue is entry is already done in DB. Now I need to write update

Comment: It is a core review_detail table, If I change detail as details, It will cause any issues related DB?? whether  will it affect any functionality

Comment: No, It will not create a any issue.

Comment: Did you have checked above query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72951/discussion-between-sri-and-suresh-chikani).

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that your join is already set. What you could is to check whether the join was already set or not.

Something like this:

```
try {
    $this->getSelect()->join(
        ['details' => $this->getReviewDetailTable()], 'main_table.review_id = details.review_id',
        ['detail_id', 'title', 'detail', 'nickname', 'customer_id']
    );
} catch (\Exception $e) {
 ...
}
```

I would change the alias `details` to something more unique.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has an accepted answer but in this case the line **parent::_iniselect()** is doing reference to

> \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Collection

(the new parent) which extends from:

> \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection

(the original parent) so you should change it for

> \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection::_initSelect();

as shown below:

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    //parent::_initSelect();
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection::_initSelect();

    $this->getSelect()->join(
        ['detail' => $this->getReviewDetailTable()],
        'main_table.review_id = detail.review_id',
        ['detail_id', 'title', 'detail', 'nickname', 'customer_id']
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution of yours but am getting an error where it says protectedMethod _initSelect cannot be accessed in public. I am trying to write my stuff after the _initSelect in Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection using after_initSelect. Got any advice?

Comment: This does not provide answer. If you have any question, you can ask as per `https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask`

Comment: @pawan, Noted. Thank you. Created another questionable post for this. Kindly let me know if you can help.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/339946/initselect-override-with-plugin-in-magento2-4-1