# _initSelect override with Plugin in Magento2.4.1

Tags: php, magento2.4, magento2.4.1, override-model, after-plugin

Need a help in this issue. I am trying to remove a MySQL condition from _initSelect from this Collection "**Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection**". This Collection has the following _initSelect.

```
public function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['rule_coupons' => $this->getTable('salesrule_coupon')],
            'main_table.rule_id = rule_coupons.rule_id AND rule_coupons.is_primary = 1',
            ['code']
        );
        return $this;
    }
```

I am trying to modify the sql conditions using after_initSelect in a Plugin as follows.

```
namespace myModule\Promotion\Model\Plugin\Rule;

class RuleCollection
{
    public function after_initSelect(\Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection $subject, $result) {

        \Magento\Rule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection\AbstractCollection::_initSelect();
        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['rule_coupons' => $this->getTable('salesrule_coupon')],
            'main_table.rule_id = rule_coupons.rule_id AND rule_coupons.is_primary = 0',
            ['code']
        );
        return $this;
    }
}
```

My Plugin is getting recognized but this line "\Magento\Rule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection\AbstractCollection::_initSelect();" is throwing me errors saying "**Error: Call to protected method Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection::_initSelect()**".

Can anyone help with what am I missing. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `plugin` to override `protected method`. plugins cannot override protected method.
So use `preference` instead of using plugin to override protected